# What is the correct substitute for doLayout in ExtJS 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

So `doLayout` was removed from `Ext.Container` in ExtJS 6 and I'm trying to figure out what's the proper substitute of it. Or is it just not necessary at all to do a call to a method to refresh the layout ? and I'm using `updateLayout` but I'm not sure this is the way to go.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: `updateLayout` would be the equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Evan, answering super fast as always dude!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**updateLayout** is the answer. doLayout has been deprecated and no longer valid.

[API Docs Link here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.container.Viewport.html#method-updateLayout)

Updates this component's layout. If this update affects this components ownerCt, that component's updateLayout method will be called to perform the layout instead. Otherwise, just this component (and its child items) will layout.